# PHP file upload not saving file

Tags: php, file, upload, ftp, save

i want to write a PHP uploader, which saves files onto my FTP.

I found this script:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

I added a 0 to the max filesize value, because i wanted to test with an 160kb image.

Everything works fine. It even says:

```
Upload: bier15291.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 158.26171875 kB
Temp file: /mnt/shared/tmp/php_0aOep
Stored in: upload/bier15291.jpg
```

But i cant find the file on my FTP.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: And you are _absolutely_ sure, that there is write permissions to the `upload/` directory?

Comment: So is this question resolved then? If so you should pick an answer or add one yourself and choose that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to set the permissions 0775...

Answer (score 1):

Please check the return value of move_uploaded_file. If either the filename is not a valid upload file or something goes wrong with moving the file contents, move_uploaded_file will return false.

Comment: The code works just fine. When I test it, it uploads the files as expected, _after_ I have ensured write- permissions and changed `$_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)` to a more normal / larger value :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
You need some error handling at the point of your attempt to move the file, as currently you only check `IF $_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0` before you actually attempt to move the file.

So your code only confirms there are no errors on the temp file before you move it.

Consider these statements from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

> If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and
>   move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.
>
> If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some
>   reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return
>   FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

So you do right checking the temp file is all ok and no errors before working with it, but you also need to catch errors from the `move_upload_file()` function to make sure the move was TRUE or FALSE.

Do something like (I've just modified your code to add an IF around the `move_uploaded_file()`)

```
   if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
     {  
       echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
     }
   else
     {
       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
       "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
         {
           echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
         }
       else
         {
           //output the errors here (ie using $_FILES["file"]["error"])
         }
      }
```

Then the error array should output what's going wrong. Ie (likely) UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE. This will then point you to the issue, and also is good to have in your code anyway, so your script fails gracefully rather than just nothing happens (should never have a scenario where nothing happens!)